# generalizing linked list for different Node types

Tags: c, linked-list

I've two or more different kinds of structs that uses linked list of their own types of nodes, and what I'm noticing that code to retrieve, remove, insert and check if the node is present is same across all structures while code is getting duplicated across. Is there a better way?

**Cat House**

```
typedef struct Cat Cat;
struct Cat {};

typedef struct CatNode CatNode;
struct CatNode {
    char *name;
    Cat *cat;
    CatNode *next;
};

typedef struct CatHouse CatHouse;
struct CatHouse {
    CatNode *cats;
    Proxy *(*getCat)(const CatHouse *self, const char *name);
    bool (*hasCat)(const CatHouse *self, const char *name);
    Proxy *(*remove)(CatHouse *self, const char *name);
};
```

**Dog House**

```
typedef struct Dog Dog;
struct Dog {};

typedef struct DogNode DogNode;
struct DogNode {
    char *name;
    Dog *dog;
    DogNode *next;
};

typedef struct DogHouse DogHouse;
struct DogHouse {
    DogNode *dogs;
    Dog *(*getDog)(const DogHouse *self, const char *name);
    bool (*hasDog)(const DogHouse *self, const char *name);
    Dog *(*remove)(DogHouse *self, const char *name);
};
```

---

**Here's part of the implementation that's getting duplicated across both entities.**

I'm fine if duplication is how it's done and I'm also wondering how linked lists are handled in commercial projects where they have several entity structs and each with their own linked lists and perhaps more than one?

```
static bool hasCat(const Cat *self, const char *name) {
    CatNode *cursor = self->cats;
    while (cursor != NULL && strcmp(cursor->name, name) != 0)
        cursor = cursor->next;
    return cursor != NULL;
}


static bool hasDog(const Dog *self, const char *name) {
    DogNode *cursor = self->dogs;
    while (cursor != NULL && strcmp(cursor->name, name) != 0)
        cursor = cursor->next;
    return cursor != NULL;
}
```

Rest of the functions are similarly getting duplicated too except that types are different.

Comment: one way would be to use lots of macros :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use C genericity in order to have a linked list that can hold whatever you want.

One way to do that is like this :

```
typedef struct link {
    void        *data;
    struct link *previous;
    struct link *next;
} link_s;

typedef struct list {
    link_s *head;
    link_s *tail;
    size_t nbLink;

    /* function pointer */
    int    (*Data_Compare)(const void *data1, const void *data2);
    void   (*Data_Destructor)(void *data);
} list_s;
```

Then, you have to provide a function used to know which "data" is inferior, equal or superior to another (the Data_Compare function pointer, acting like strcmp), and you may providing a function that will "destroy" your data (if by example, you made memory allocation).

After that, you can have a "data" being an union of your "cat" and "dog" structure, allowing thus to have one linked list holding up all, or you can have juste two linked list, one for "cat", and other one for "dog" (mind to provide the good Data_Compare for both).

In my implementation, I provide the following function to manipulate list_s :

```
void List_Constructor(list_s *self, int (*Data_Compare)(const void *data1, const void *data2), void (*Data_Destructor)(void *data));
void List_Destructor(list_s *self);

bool List_Add(list_s *self, void *data);

void *List_RemoveByLink(list_s *self, link_s *link);
void *List_RemoveByData(list_s *self, void *data);
void *List_RemoveByCondition(list_s *self, bool (*Data_Condition)(const void *data));

void List_DestroyByLink(list_s *self, link_s *link);
/* Delete all the link corresponding to data */
void List_DestroyByData(list_s *self, void *data);
/* Delete all the link which condition is true */
void List_DestroyByCondition(list_s *self, bool (*Data_Condition)(const void *data));

void List_Sort(list_s *self);
void List_Merge(list_s *to, list_s *from);
void List_Reverse(list_s *self);
```

Edit :

In order to have thread-safety functionnality with the below example, you can make something like this :

```
typedef struct ts_list {
  list_s          list;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} ts_list_s;

void TsList_Constructor(ts_list_s *self, int (*Data_Compare)(const void *data1, const void *data2), void (*Data_Destructor)(void *data));
void TsList_Destructor(ts_list_s *self);

bool TsList_Add(ts_list_s *self, void *data);

void *TsList_RemoveByLink(ts_list_s *self, link_s *link);
void *TsList_RemoveByData(ts_list_s *self, void *data);
void *TsList_RemoveByCondition(ts_list_s *self, bool (*Data_Condition)(const void *data));

void TsList_DestroyByLink(ts_list_s *self, link_s *link);
void TsList_DestroyByData(ts_list_s *self, void *data);
void TsList_DestroyByCondition(ts_list_s *self, bool (*Data_Condition)(const void *data));

void TsList_Sort(ts_list_s *self);
void TsList_Merge(ts_list_s *to, ts_list_s *from);
void TsList_Reverse(ts_list_s *self);

// Addtionnal function, for comfort
bool TsList_LockMutex(ts_list_s *self);
bool TsList_UnlockMutex(ts_list_s *self);
```

with all TsList_* function look like :

```
bool TsList_Add(ts_list_s *self, void *data)
{
  bool returnFunction;

  if (!TsList_LockMutex(self)) {
    return (false);
  }

  returnFunction = List_Add(&self->list, data);

  if (!TsList_UnlockMutex(self)) {
    // Big critical log, because from this point, there will be deadlock
  }
  return (returnFunction);
}
```

Of course, you have to be really warry of deadlock, especially with the "List_Merge" function, since you will have to lock the two list before merging.

Comment: any single function you can provide that's thread safe or maybe use hasCat function and make it thread safe?

Comment: It's true that actually, this isn't thread safe nor reentrant by design. If you want thread safety, you will have to "associate" the list_s variable with a mutex and make thread-safe function call to all List_* function. I don't know if I'm clear, English is not my motherlangage.

Comment: no problem, can I see some code based on your comment

Comment: I've edited my answer, is this what you looking for ?

Comment: Thanks for the edits but I can't find body for `TsList_UnlockMutex` functions

Comment: Well, you have to do some work of your own, don't you think ? What do you suppose TsList_LockMutex/TsList_UnlockMutex function do ? They are "wrapper" to call ptread_lock and pthread_unlock. I do that because if you have deadlock, it can be an easy step to firstly add printf in each function in order to see where lock / unlock happen and so where deadlock happen. And if by some sort of curse the deadlock is the result of a race-condition, may the force be with you and use a debugger (but the printf-thing is surprislingly efficient sometime).

Comment: I just wanted to compare my locking piece of code with yours to see if it's correct. Secondly you think there could be race condition like if two threads are trying to get a lock and both will get a lock?

Comment: In order to do the merge, you will have to lock "to", and after you will have to lock "from". What happen if in thread1 you do "TsList_Merge(&list1, &list2);" and on thread2 you do "TsList_Merge(&list2, &list1);" ? Without any other synchronisation, you have the possibility that the thread1 lock list1, be suspended, and then thread2 lock list2, try to lock1 but can't because thread1 already have done it. It's, from my point of view, best to not implemente TsList_Merge at all, since the deadlock is possible by design.

Comment: As for the locking piece of code, be more confident in you. I understand that is hard to do a function when you don't know how the other one is thinking, but try to do something you think is rigth, and when it failed, keep trying a little. If after that, you're still stuck, do not hesitate to come again and ask.

Comment: Hi Tom, I realized something that I shouldn't be using a generalized list and just go with duplicate crud functions for each struct, the reason has to do with threading block, let's say I've two lists and they belong to two different struct objects, if I add/delete item from one, I don't want to block the other list because it's items are different. By generalizing we are sharing code between lists and blocking on one list blocks everyone else.

Comment: I mean like why block dog list if you are adding cats to the list as per my question,

Comment: As I have say before, with a generic linked list, you can do whatever you want. If you want one list to contain all dog and cat, then you can (even if you have to make a good comparaison function). Personnaly, I prefere to do one list for dog and another list for cat.
The purpose of the generic linked list is to not rewrite linked list function each time you want to do a linked list of X, or of Y, or of Z, or of X and Z at the same time. The multi-threading context is a different problem and have barely something to do with the generic linked list.

Comment: So, yeah, just make two linked list, one for dog, and another one for cat.